# Format an Excel column (or cell) as Text in C#?

Tags: c#, excel, export-to-excel

I am losing the leading zeros when I copy values from a datatable to an Excel sheet. That's because probably Excel treats the values as a number instead of text.

I am copying the values like so:

```
myWorksheet.Cells[i + 2, j] = dtCustomers.Rows[i][j - 1].ToString();
```

How do I format a whole column or each cell as Text?

A related question, how to cast `myWorksheet.Cells[i + 2, j]`  to show a style property in Intellisense?

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648149/what-are-numberformat-options-in-excel-vba/49621979#49621979

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Below is some code to format columns A and C as text in [SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) which has an API which is similar to Excel - except for the fact that SpreadsheetGear is frequently more strongly typed. It should not be too hard to figure out how to convert this to work with Excel / COM:

```
IWorkbook workbook = Factory.GetWorkbook();
IRange cells = workbook.Worksheets[0].Cells;
// Format column A as text.
cells["A:A"].NumberFormat = "@";
// Set A2 to text with a leading '0'.
cells["A2"].Value = "01234567890123456789";
// Format column C as text (SpreadsheetGear uses 0 based indexes - Excel uses 1 based indexes).
cells[0, 2].EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "@";
// Set C3 to text with a leading '0'.
cells[2, 2].Value = "01234567890123456789";
workbook.SaveAs(@"c:\tmp\TextFormat.xlsx", FileFormat.OpenXMLWorkbook);
```

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC

Answer (score 16):

If you set the cell formatting to Text **prior** to adding a numeric value with a leading zero, the leading zero is retained without having to skew results by adding an apostrophe. If you try and manually add a leading zero value to a default sheet in Excel and then convert it to text, the leading zero is removed. If you convert the cell to Text first, then add your value, it is fine. Same principle applies when doing it programatically.

```
        // Pull in all the cells of the worksheet
        Range cells = xlWorkBook.Worksheets[1].Cells;
        // set each cell's format to Text
        cells.NumberFormat = "@";
        // reset horizontal alignment to the right
        cells.HorizontalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;

        // now add values to the worksheet
        for (i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j <= dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1; j++)
            {
                DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1[j, i];
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = cell.Value.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 15):

Solution that worked for me for Excel Interop:

```
myWorksheet.Columns[j].NumberFormat = "@";      // column as a text
myWorksheet.Cells[i + 2, j].NumberFormat = "@"; // cell as a text
```

This code should run **before** putting data to Excel. Column and row numbers are 1-based.

A bit more details. Whereas accepted response with reference for SpreadsheetGear looks almost correct, I had two concerns about it:

1. I am not using SpreadsheetGear. I was interested in regular Excel
   communication thru Excel interop without any 3rdparty libraries,
2. I was searching for the way to format column by number, not using
   ranges like "A:A".

Answer (score 7):

Before your write to Excel need to change the format:

```
xlApp = New Excel.Application
xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim cells As Excel.Range = xlWorkSheet.Cells

'set each cell's format to Text
cells.NumberFormat = "@"

'reset horizontal alignment to the right
cells.HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight
```

Answer (score 4):

I've recently battled with this problem as well, and I've learned two things about the above suggestions.

1. Setting the numberFormatting to @ causes Excel to left-align the value, and read it as if it were text, however, it still truncates the leading zero.
2. Adding an apostrophe at the beginning results in Excel treating it as text and retains the zero, and then applies the default text format, solving both problems.

The misleading aspect of this is that you now have a different value in the cell.  Fortuately, when you copy/paste or export to CSV, the apostrophe is not included.

Conclusion: use the apostrophe, not the numberFormatting in order to retain the leading zeros.

Comment: Both setting the NumberFormat = "@" and prefixing the value with an apostrophe retained leading zeros for me.

When using the NumberFormat method, to retain right alignment in the column, you can simply add the following:

`rng.NumberFormat = "@";
rng.HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight`;


Or one of the other alignment methods found here:
[link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(MICROSOFT.OFFICE.INTEROP.EXCEL.RANGE.HORIZONTALALIGNMENT);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true

Answer (score 3):

Use your `WorkSheet.Columns.NumberFormat`, and set it to `string "@"`, here is the sample:

```
Excel._Worksheet workSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)_Excel.Worksheets.Add();
//set columns format to text format
workSheet.Columns.NumberFormat = "@";
```

Note: this text format will apply for your hole excel sheet!

If you want a particular column to apply the text format, for example, the first column, you can do this:

```
workSheet.Columns[0].NumberFormat = "@";
```

or this will apply the specified range of woorkSheet to text format:

```
workSheet.get_Range("A1", "D1").NumberFormat = "@";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   if (dtCustomers.Columns[j - 1].DataType != typeof(decimal) && dtCustomers.Columns[j - 1].DataType != typeof(int))
   {
      myWorksheet.Cells[i + 2, j].NumberFormat = "@";
   }
```

Comment: How to achieve the above request without excel interop

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is aged, still, I would like to contribute.

Applying `Range.NumberFormat = "@"` just partially solve the problem:

- Yes, if you place the focus on a cell of the range, you will read **text** in the format menu
- Yes, it align the data to the left
- But if you use the **type** formula to check the type of the value in the cell, it will return **1 meaning number**

Applying the apostroph behave better. It sets the format to **text**, it align data to left and if you check the format of the value in the cell using the **type** formula, it will return **2 meaning text**

Answer (score 0):

```
//where [1] - column number which you want to make text

ExcelWorksheet.Columns[1].NumberFormat = "@";


//If you want to format a particular column in all sheets in a workbook - use below code. Remove loop for single sheet along with slight changes.

  //path were excel file is kept


     string ResultsFilePath = @"C:\\Users\\krakhil\\Desktop\\TGUW EXCEL\\TEST";

            Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook ExcelWorkbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(ResultsFilePath);
            ExcelApp.Visible = true;

            //Looping through all available sheets
            foreach (Excel.Worksheet ExcelWorksheet in ExcelWorkbook.Sheets)
            {                
                //Selecting the worksheet where we want to perform action
                ExcelWorksheet.Select(Type.Missing);
                ExcelWorksheet.Columns[1].NumberFormat = "@";
            }

            //saving excel file using Interop
            ExcelWorkbook.Save();

            //closing file and releasing resources
            ExcelWorkbook.Close(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(ExcelWorkbook);
            ExcelApp.Quit();
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(ExcelApp);
```

Comment: i am having problem with comma seprator data like this 12345,1234,1234,3456 will it solve my problem ?

Comment: @DeepakJain - Did your problem solve? If not, update me, i will help

Comment: nope.i am importing dataset to excel and one of the excel sheet cantains a column which has Data like this 123,124,12534,123450,876 and Excel not able to show the data properly.

Comment: my code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48891182/garbage-data-coming-while-importing-dataset-to-excel-for-number-with

Comment: **You just have to change the format of that column or cell to text.**

'//Format to text
    ExcelWorksheet.Columns[1].NumberFormat = "@";'

 if you are still having trouble let me know. As i was able to solve this on my end.

Comment: ` ExcelWorksheet.Columns[1].NumberFormat = "@";`

Answer (score 0):

You need to format the column to be a string.

You can use the link https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t679279/import-from-excel-to-gridview

For converting the ExcelDataSource, you can also refer to https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t468253/how-to-convert-exceldatasource-to-datatable

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).