# C# Excel Interop: How to format cells to store values as text

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I'm writing numbers to an Excel spreadsheet from a `DataTable` and all of these numbers are 5 digits long with preceding 0s if the number itself is less than 5 digits long (so 395 would be stored as 00395, for example).

When entering these numbers into Excel (using C#), it's storing them as numbers and eliminating the preceding 0s. Is there any way I can format the cells from C# in order to get the values to be stored as text rather than numbers?

Comment: See this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067926/format-an-excel-column-or-cell-as-text-in-c

Comment: @Katit: While the question matches, the answer here is better IMHO as it doesn't rely on third-party libraries.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can `SomeRange.NumberFormat = "@";` or if you prefix the value with a `'` and write it to the cell excel will treat it as a number-stored-as-text and provide a visual cue.

Answer (score 2):

This answer just solved a major problem with a solution from one of our company's software, I had to retrieve the value as displayed, but once I set it to the new sheet, it was being inserted as a number. 
Simple solution.
I cant vote up as yet, but down follows how it ended up.

```
for (int h = 1; h <= 1; h++)
{
    int col = lastColl(sheets);
    for (int r = 1; r <= src.Count; r++)
    {
        sheets.Cells[r, col + 1] = "'"+src.Cells[r, h].Text.ToString().Trim();
    }
}
```

Comment: This works whereas the solution to change the NumberFormat does not work in my case with a FedEx tracking code (14 digits).

Answer (score 0):

//where [1] is column number which you want to make text

```
ExcelWorksheet.Columns[1].NumberFormat = "@";
```

//If you want to format a particular column in all sheets in a workbook - use below code. Remove loop for single sheet along with slight changes.

//path were excel file is kept

string ResultsFilePath = @"C:\Users\krakhil\Desktop\TGUW EXCEL\TEST";

```
    Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook ExcelWorkbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(ResultsFilePath);
    ExcelApp.Visible = true;

    //Looping through all available sheets
    foreach (Excel.Worksheet ExcelWorksheet in ExcelWorkbook.Sheets)
    {                
        //Selecting the worksheet where we want to perform action
        ExcelWorksheet.Select(Type.Missing);
        ExcelWorksheet.Columns[1].NumberFormat = "@";
    }

    //saving excel file using Interop
    ExcelWorkbook.Save();

    //closing file and releasing resources
    ExcelWorkbook.Close(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(ExcelWorkbook);
    ExcelApp.Quit();
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(ExcelApp);
```