# String type value added to Excel cell, but it shown like double

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, export-to-excel, excel-interop

I set a value in string type to Excell cell, but in result it shows like numeric format.

```
workSheet.Cells[i + 1, 7] = list[i].Code;
```

`Code` is a `string` type, but in result it shown like double. For example, Code is **"409318000597"** in string type, but in excell value is **4,09318E+11**. When I double clicked to cell, it expands and shown like **409318000597** and get back on mouse over.

I also tried this, but nothing changed.

```
workSheet.Cells[i + 1, 7] = String.Format("{0}", list[i].Code);
```

It is interesting that, there is `Name` property in string type also, it shown like normal.

Is there any way to manage excel types?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Excel Interop: How to format cells to store values as text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583704/c-sharp-excel-interop-how-to-format-cells-to-store-values-as-text) and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067926/format-an-excel-column-or-cell-as-text-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `NumberFormat` to text:

```
workSheet.Cells[i + 1, 7].NumberFormat = "@";
workSheet.Cells[i + 1, 7] = list[i].Code;
```

Actually I suggest you to do it for entire range:

```
workSheet.Range["G1","G100"].NumberFormat = "@";
```

and then in loop:

```
workSheet.Cells[i + 1, 7] = list[i].Code;
```