# What are .NumberFormat Options In Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Can you please let me know what are the `.NumberFormat` format options in Excel VBA? As you are fully aware Excel 2010 supports the following types:

[image]

I know that we can set for example Text type as:

```
.NumberFormat ="@"
```

or for number:

```
.NumberFormat = "0.00000"
```

Can you please let me know what are other options for types in VBA?

Comment: Why don't you record a macro and check?

Comment: In the `Format Cell` dialog, click on the format type you want (eg.,'Accounting`), and then click `Custom`. The list on the bottom right shows the current `Accounting` format string (along with others). The textbox above shows you the `NumberFormat` string for that item. You can copy/paste right from that textbox into a string in your code.

Comment: Here's a somewhat goofy, but colorful, custom format preview web page that I created: http://yoursumbuddy.com/preview-excel-custom-formats/

Answer (score 97):

Note this was done on Excel for Mac 2011 but should be same for Windows

Macro:

```
Sub numberformats()
  Dim rng As Range
  Set rng = Range("A24:A35")
  For Each c In rng
    Debug.Print c.NumberFormat
  Next c
End Sub
```

Result:

```
General     General
Number      0
Currency    $#,##0.00;[Red]$#,##0.00
Accounting  _($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* "-"??_);_(@_)
Date        m/d/yy
Time        [$-F400]h:mm:ss am/pm
Percentage  0.00%
Fraction    # ?/?
Scientific  0.00E+00
Text        @
Special     ;;
Custom      #,##0_);[Red](#,##0)
```

(I just picked a random entry for custom)

Comment: The "s of Accounting need to be escaped, `""` to prevent bugs in vba that uses that code.

Comment: I need to know what you meant by 'escaped'.  Are you saying that we need to double quote the hashmark (-) in order for this to work in VBA?

Comment: Personally, I prefer & chr(34) & - it's much cleaner

Comment: The escaped version used in actual code looks like this:  `YourRange.NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"`.  If you want the cleaner look @Selkie mentioned above it looks like this:  `YourRange.NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* " & Chr(34) & "-" & Chr(34) & "??_);_(@_)"`.

Answer (score 23):

Thanks to this question (and answers), I discovered an easy way to get at the exact NumberFormat string for virtually any format that Excel has to offer.

---

### How to Obtain the NumberFormat String for Any Excel Number Format

---

**Step 1**: In the user interface, set a cell to the NumberFormat you want to use.

[image: I manually formatted a cell to Chinese (PRC) currency]

In my example, I selected the Chinese (PRC) Currency from the options contained in the "Account Numbers Format" combo box.

**Step 2**: Expand the Number Format dropdown and select "More Number Formats...".

[image: Open the Number Format dropdown]

**Step 3**: In the Number tab, in Category, click "Custom".

[image: Click Custom]

The "Sample" section shows the Chinese (PRC) currency formatting that I applied.

The "Type" input box contains the NumberFormat string that you can use programmatically.

So, in this example, the NumberFormat of my Chinese (PRC) Currency cell is as follows:

```
_ [$¥-804]* #,##0.00_ ;_ [$¥-804]* -#,##0.00_ ;_ [$¥-804]* "-"??_ ;_ @_
```

If you do these steps for each NumberFormat that you desire, then the world is yours.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I tried your approach, but while I did figure out the format I wanted, the world is still not mine. Please advice ;)

Comment: You are 100% correct. My youthful optimism did not age well!

Answer (score 9):

**dovers** gives us his great answer and based on it you can try use it like

```
public static class CellDataFormat
{
        public static string General { get { return "General"; } }
        public static string Number { get { return "0"; } }

        // Your custom format 
        public static string NumberDotTwoDigits { get { return "0.00"; } }

        public static string Currency { get { return "$#,##0.00;[Red]$#,##0.00"; } }
        public static string Accounting { get { return "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* \" - \"??_);_(@_)"; } }
        public static string Date { get { return "m/d/yy"; } }
        public static string Time { get { return "[$-F400] h:mm:ss am/pm"; } }
        public static string Percentage { get { return "0.00%"; } }
        public static string Fraction { get { return "# ?/?"; } }
        public static string Scientific { get { return "0.00E+00"; } }
        public static string Text { get { return "@"; } }
        public static string Special { get { return ";;"; } }
        public static string Custom { get { return "#,##0_);[Red](#,##0)"; } }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In Excel, you can set a `Range.NumberFormat` to any string as you would find in the "Custom" format selection.  Essentially, you have two choices:

1. **General** for no particular format.
2. A custom formatted string, like "$#,##0", to specify exactly what format you're using.

Answer (score 3):

The .NET Library [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/) implements a conversation from the string definition to the built in number.
See class [ExcelNumberFormat](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/blob/master/EPPlus/Style/ExcelNumberFormat.cs):

```cs
internal static int GetFromBuildIdFromFormat(string format)
{
    switch (format)
    {
        case "General":
            return 0;
        case "0":
            return 1;
        case "0.00":
            return 2;
        case "#,##0":
            return 3;
        case "#,##0.00":
            return 4;
        case "0%":
            return 9;
        case "0.00%":
            return 10;
        case "0.00E+00":
            return 11;
        case "# ?/?":
            return 12;
        case "# ??/??":
            return 13;
        case "mm-dd-yy":
            return 14;
        case "d-mmm-yy":
            return 15;
        case "d-mmm":
            return 16;
        case "mmm-yy":
            return 17;
        case "h:mm AM/PM":
            return 18;
        case "h:mm:ss AM/PM":
            return 19;
        case "h:mm":
            return 20;
        case "h:mm:ss":
            return 21;
        case "m/d/yy h:mm":
            return 22;
        case "#,##0 ;(#,##0)":
            return 37;
        case "#,##0 ;[Red](#,##0)":
            return 38;
        case "#,##0.00;(#,##0.00)":
            return 39;
        case "#,##0.00;[Red](#,#)":
            return 40;
        case "mm:ss":
            return 45;
        case "[h]:mm:ss":
            return 46;
        case "mmss.0":
            return 47;
        case "##0.0":
            return 48;
        case "@":
            return 49;
        default:
            return int.MinValue;
    }
}
```

When you use one of these formats, Excel will automatically identify them as a standard format.