# How do I add a zero after the decimal when coding in excel

Tags: excel

I am having trouble adding a zero after the decimal when coding in excel. The number that is being output is 240 and I want it to say 240.0. I have tried the round function in excel however that is only working when I have something like 242.46 and it gaves me 242.5.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you mean by coding? With VBA? Can you show us what you tried with code?

Comment: If it's just in a cell on a worksheet, there is an 'increase decimal' button on the home ribbon (number section) that should do it.

Comment: ElevImp = Round(ElevVal, 1)

Comment: that is something I have and I want to be able to make the number be 240.0 instead of 240

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
oWrkSheet.Cells(110, 17).NumberFormat = "0.0"
```

It can work for many other numeric formats. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648149/what-are-numberformat-options-in-excel-vba) for more informations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formula:

```
=TEXT(A1,"0.0")
```

Either change `A1` to the appropriate cell, or surround the cell in question with a `=TEXT(...,"0.0")`