# VBA: divide value directly to cell is integer

Tags: vba, excel

I have this formula, which takes two numbers in two cells, performs a division and places the value into a cell. However, this method causes the output to be a integer value.

```
wsProt.Range("E" & pdTableCount).Value = wsProt.Range("F" & pdTableCount).Value / wsProt.Range("D" & pdTableCount).Value
```

Is there a way to do this that will cause the value to be a value that provides for a decimal  part without having to use an intermediary variable?

Also, I don't want the cell to be a formula, I just want the actual value for the division.

thanks!

Comment: Format cell to include decimals?

Comment: You could use the `.NumberFormat` property to specify the exact number of decimal places: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648149/what-are-numberformat-options-in-excel-vba

Comment: `.Value` isn't an `Integer`, it's a `Variant` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx), the output of your algorithm will only be an `Integer` if the quotient is a whole number, otherwise it'll be a `Double`. If you think the result should be a `Double` but you're not seeing one, then the problem probably lies in your cell formatting.

Comment: will you supply the actual values so we can double check?

Comment: well now I'm just annoyed. I turned on my my laptop this morning, opened up the spreadsheet, ran it again to see how the cell format affects the situation and now the number being placed in the cell contains the full expected decimal without having changed anything.