# Currency format is excelJS

Tags: exceljs

How do you format currency in exceljs?

All I've found is this from their docs...which I have no clue how to type so I pasted it, but it doesn't seem to work

```
// Set Column 3 to Currency Format 
ws.getColumn(3).numFmt = '�#,##0;[Red]-�#,##0';
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just took a little bit of tinkering with.

```
ws.getColumn(3).numFmt = '$#,##0.00;[Red]-$#,##0.00';
```

The #'s are optional digits. If you don't care about negative numbers being red you can leave it as `$#,##0.00`

Comment: What about accounting format with parenthesis for negatives? Is there a preset format or do you have to mask it like this?

Comment: For parentheses: `'$#,##0.00;[Red]($#,##0.00)'`

Answer (score 6):

For the full Accounting format, eg left-justified '$', `$-` for $0.00, etc, you can use:

```
const numFmtStr = '_("$"* #,##0.00_);_("$"* (#,##0.00);_("$"* "-"??_);_(@_)';
cell.numFmt = numFmtStr;
```

see: [What are .NumberFormat Options In Excel VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648149/what-are-numberformat-options-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 0):

An alternate to 343_Guilty_Spark's answer which is shorter and will be red for negative values:

```
const numFmtStr = '$#,##0.00_);[Red]($#,##0.00)'
cell.numFmt = numFmtStr
```

This will keep all the qualities of it, but be less complicated for Excel.