# How to use Powershell to enforce formatting of an Excel Column?

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm writing a Powershell script to enforce "General Formatting" of Column AI. This is what I have and it didn't appear to execute.

```
$worksheet.columns.items('AI').GeneralFormat = $true
```

What is the right Powershell code for such a task?

General Formatting:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The clue is in your screenshot; the tooltip specifies this is the "Number Format" setting.

```
$worksheet.Columns("AI").NumberFormat = "General"
```

Check out the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196401.aspx) on `NumberFormat`. Unfortunately it doesn't list the allowed values; this [StackOverflow q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648149/what-are-numberformat-options-in-excel-vba) appears to cover that.

Answer (score 3):

This works

```
$Excel01 = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel01.Visible = $True
$Workbook01 = $Excel01.Workbooks.Add()
$Worksheet01 = $Workbook01.Sheets.Item(1)
$Worksheet01.Activate()
$Excel01.Columns.item('d').NumberFormat = "0"
```

Comment: What value does this add over the accepted answer posted a year earlier?