# Percentage value get rounded when exporting from excel to csv

Tags: excel, powershell

I need a script to convert Excel data files to a CSV format. I used the following snippet of code. The code works however one of the columns in the data is a percentage and the resulting csv file has a rounded value of the percentages (4.55914% -> 4.56%).

```
  $extension = ((Split-Path $FilePath -Leaf).Split('.'))[1]
  if($extension -eq "xls" -or $extension -eq "xlsx") {
        Write-Host "Converting to CSV: $FilePath" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
        $wb = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath, $false, $true)
        
        #$wb.WorkSheets(1).Columns.Item(3).NumberFormat = "Text"
        Write-Host (( $wb.WorkSheets(1).Columns.Item(3).NumberFormat )| Format-List | Out-String)
        
        $fileName = Split-Path $FilePath -Leaf
        $tempFile = Join-Path $tempFilesDir $fileName 
        $FilePath = $tempFile -replace $extension, "csv"
        
        $ws = $wb.Worksheets.Item(1)
        $Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
        
        $ws.SaveAs($FilePath, 6)
        Write-Host "CSV File Saved: $FilePath" -ForegroundColor Green
        $Excel.Quit()
    }
```

I tried updating the column's number format first `$wb.WorkSheets(1).Columns.Item(3).NumberFormat = "@#.########%"` However that threw this error `Unable to set the NumberFormat property of the Range class`. I tried to solve this error to by adding

```
$wb.WorkSheets(1).Protect('',0,1,0,0,1,1,1)
$wb.WorkSheets(1).Columns.Item(3).NumberFormat = "@##.######%"
```

This did not work and gave me the same error. Next, I tried `$wb.WorkSheets(1).Columns.Item(3).NumberFormat = "Text"` This did not give me an error but instead converted all of my values to `T1900xt` I have no idea why this would happen.

Are there any other solutions I can try before resorting to looping through the file?

Comment: Try `"0.000000%"`.

Comment: Unrelated side note. `Split-Path` has a `-Extension` parameter. And you can use `$extension -in ('.xls','.xlsx')`

Comment: @BigBen "@0.000000%" gave me to same 'Unable to set the NumberFormat property of the Range class error'

Comment: Why are you using an `@`? That's not what I suggested.

Comment: @BigBen, you are correct. without the '@' worked. I was under the impression that '@' denoted a formatting string. Thank you

Comment: `@` is the number format for Text. It doesn't belong in numeric formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your number format is incorrect:

```
.NumberFormat = "@##.######%"
```

The `@` denotes the Text format string and does not belong in a numeric format string.

Use:

```
.NumberFormat = "0.000000%"
```

You could see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648149/what-are-numberformat-options-in-excel-vba) for other format options.