# how to format the excel to treat the cell value as text by appending an apostrophe to the cell value in c#

Tags: c#, excel, model-view-controller, datatables

I'm generating excel report in `c#` in excel.binding data to excel through datatable.

There is one column which will consist of 16 digit number for eg.,`1317722825000285` but in excel it is coming as `1317722825000280` last digit is getting replaced by `0`.

So how to can I format this column value as excel Text ?

Answer (score 0):

There's a great post here that may answer your question: [Format an Excel column (or cell) as Text in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067926/format-an-excel-column-or-cell-as-text-in-c)

Try formatting the cell as text and making your variable a string in C# before inserting.

Hope this helps.