# Format excel destination column in ssis script task

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl, script-task

Is it possible to format a column in an excel destination in ssis before generating it? I'm thinking a script task? I want to format a column to be date/time format within the excel spreadsheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Microsoft.Interop.Excel` library and use `NumberFormat` property to change `EntireColumn` format to datetime.

*Note: you have to add `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll` file to the following directories (.Net Framework dll directory)  `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727` and (sql server data tools dll directory) `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn` (if using vs 2005 and sql 2008) and then add this dll as a reference in your script task*

```vb
Imports Microsoft.Interop.Excel

Public Sub Main()

        Dim m_XlApp = New Excel.Application
        Dim m_xlWrkbs As Excel.Workbooks = m_XlApp.Workbooks
        Dim m_xlWrkb As Excel.Workbook
        m_xlWrkb = m_xlWrkbs.Open("D:\1.xlsx")

        Dim m_XlWrkSheet As Excel.Worksheet = m_xlWrkb.Worksheets(1)

        m_XlWrkSheet.Columns(1).NumberFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
        'OR
        'ExcelWorksheet.Cells(1,1).EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "HH:mm:ss"

        m_xlWrkb.Save()
        m_xlWrkb.Close(SaveChanges:=True)

        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(m_xlWrkb)
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(m_xlWrkbs)
        m_XlApp.Quit()
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(m_XlApp)


        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success

End Sub
```

**References**

- [Format an Excel column (or cell) as Text in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067926/format-an-excel-column-or-cell-as-text-in-c) *Look at all answers, not aonly the accepted one*
- [Interop.Excel - Set date format](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/253b580d-6103-4fbf-a650-8eaad1f3ee56/interopexcel-set-date-format?forum=csharpgeneral)
- [Range.NumberFormat Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.numberformat(office.11).aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think my issue might be because the column is set to text in the Database. so I have column A which is a time value (column data type set to text) and I have a duration column (also set as text) I use a cast in my SQL statement to add these values together to get a end time and output as a time value. this displays fine is SQL Server its when SSIS exports as excel that the time value does not show correctly. so I think the best way is to script the excel cell to be a time format is that correct?

Comment: Yes script task will solve the issue. Also it is good to try changing column datatype from the Excel Destination advanced editor. Just right click on this components and click on `Show advanced editor`.

Comment: I see that you asked a new question about this issue. So if this answer solved the questiin just accept it.

Comment: @sql2015 the other question you asked can be solved in this way. have you tried my answer?

Comment: yes I managed to get date/time showing in excel by going through the show advanced editor and changing the data type that way and correctly shows the date and time but doesn't show the seconds which I need

Comment: Then you have to use a script task like shown in the answer. Excel use current culture format by default

Comment: I'm new to C# so trying to get my head round it