# SSIS data going into excel destination incorrectly

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl, time-format

in an SSIS package I import data from a flat file into a db, do a sql query and export results into a excel destination. my issue is I have a convert,cast statement which is fine in sql it returns a value as `HH:MM:SS`. the field is a string. my issue is when it goes into excel it is displaying the column data as `MM:SS:0` i need it to stay as HH:MM:SS I have tried to use a data conversion and derived column. but I cannot seem to achieve this. 
 in my sql db I have 2 fields that are datatype 'nvarchar' I want to add them together so have the following

```
CONVERT(varchar(8), CAST(time as datetime) + CAST(length as datetime), 108) as 'endtime',
```

this returns values like `14:22:01` when it exports into excel it is appearing as `22:01:0`

any advice would be much appreciated

Comment: Excel does whatever it likes unfortunately. I don't know of a way to force excels formatting except to use automation to format the column afterwards. Not if you manually format the column the data will come through OK

Comment: ye if I manually change the excel column format to time is changes correctly. I just need t achieve this without manually changing

Comment: Here's a sample of some code (that can be run in a SSIS task) that formats coumns: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/57e84b3f-1f92-4d8c-8603-91899b2a3419/formatting-excel-text-to-currency-using-ssis-script-task?forum=sqlintegrationservices Excel will need to be installed in your SSIS server in order for this to work. Are you exporting data to excel to upload it into a different system, or is this some kind of report?

Comment: no the excel spreadsheet gets generated on server then emailed out as a report. I was just looking into scripts now, I'm new to SSIS so just trying to get my head round it

Comment: So it's a report so formatting is critical. You know that SSRS is generally better for formatting reports? SSIS is not really a report builder

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, I agree! You can also export the SSRS as Excel

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid you should compile all these comments into an answer so that the question can be closed.

Comment: Why not convert the string to `TIME` instead of `VARCHAR(8)` before exporting into Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format Excel column using a Script Task.

You have to use an Excel manipulation library like `Micsoroft.Interop.Excel` to 
change the format of the column to `HH:mm:ss`.

You can get a working example from the following question:

- [Format excel destination column in ssis script task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48093071/format-excel-destination-column-in-ssis-script-task/48094090#48094090)